# Can Amazon know about the books I upload to my Kindle device?

Tags: kindle, amazon, privacy

One user can upload her/his own ebook files onto a Kindle device .

**I'd want to know if Amazon is able to know what you are uploading on the device or not**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it is possible, it is improbable as long as you ensure all data capabilities of the device are always off. If they are ever turned on, there would be nothing stopping Amazon from snooping what's on your device. Furthermore, if it's 3G enabled, you have no guarantee that it doesn't switch on data without your knowledge and snoops your files.

Comment: OK. Now, guaranteed that it is technically feasible. Is that documented? I mean, do they state that in the 1 terabyte gibberish of licence that you have to agree to use their device and services? If anybody knows.

Comment: It isn't declared outright, but here are some points of note. 

_Information Received. The Software will provide Amazon with information about use of your Kindle or Reading Application and its interaction with Digital Content and the Service (such as last page read, content archiving, available memory, up-time, log files, voice information, and signal strength). Information provided to Amazon may be stored on servers outside the country in which you live. We will handle any information we receive in accordance with the  Amazon.com Privacy Notice._

Comment: Pulled from http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200506200. The Amazon.com Privacy Notice is a dinosaur, but I couldn't see anything about it turning on your device without  your knowledge: http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=468496

Comment: @komali_2, This doesn't tell anything because that kind of privacy policy exists for *all* companies, not just Amazon alone.  The correct way to answer this question is to setup a network monitor on the phone and see if there are any data sent to Amazon server.

Comment: @Pacerier we can safely assume amazon isn't taking the massive legal and PR risk of violating it's own privacy policy. Anyway, if you can answer the question better than "it is technically possible but improbable" with an "it's impossible"  or "it is happening," you're welcome to.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. A Kindle is an Amazon device, loaded with Amazon software, with communications capabilities. It absolutely is possible for the Kindle to phone home to Amazon and let it know what you have loaded.

Comment: He's likely more interested in "does Amazon do it?"

Comment: @Pacerier He asked whether they were "able" to do it. There's no sure way to know whether they do, but it's certainly possible.

Answer (score -2):

If you are side loading an ebook onto kindle device, there is no way for Amazon to identify this transfer.

If you are purchasing from Amazon store, the purchased ebooks can be downloaded only in your registered kindle device.

Comment: Is this documented officially? Many thanks.

Comment: I don't find any official document on this. Will let you know if any available.

Comment: This is simply incorrect. You say "there is no way for Amazon to identify this transfer." But it's an Amazon device, loaded with Amazon software, with communications capabilities. It absolutely is possible for the Kindle to phone home to Amazon and let it know what you have loaded.